# Using mouse scroll with Multitail

Tags: tail, multitail

Is there any way to use the mouse wheel, or the terminal window slide bar, to look through a `multitail` log?

Ideally `multitail` would work almost exactly like `tail` (except with the obvious coloring).

Comment: Not without modifying the program (there's no mouse code in multitail).

Comment: If you pose that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without modifying the program (there's no mouse code in multitail).  It uses ncurses, but uses none of the [mouse-support functions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_mouse.3x.html).  You can see this by inspecting the [source-code](https://github.com/flok99/multitail).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code changed since 2017 and multitail has now much more tails then in 2017. In the Debian version actually I was able to use the mouse after I changed the following in /etc/multitail.conf
the shell to bash in line line 1046

```
shell:/bin/bash
```

and in 1151 I changed to yes

```
scrollback_show_winnrs:yes
```

Comment: Did not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Ubuntu 22.04, multitail work with mouse out of the box, no need specific config.